# If dropdown value is selected add formatting and values to cells to the right

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Ok so I am making a sheet where a user would select a value from a dropdown and then needs to see the required parameters based on the selection.

Example:

If i select X from the drop down then three new input fields would be created and formatted as input cells with the parameter as the default value (so the yellowish orange input format with default text explaining what the parameter is -- like start date for one then the next end date)

My start:

```
Sub test()
If ActiveCell = "setEnrollnet" Then
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = startDate
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1) = 0
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = endDate
   ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 2) = 0

End If
End Sub
```

This does not work well and it does not apply formatting. I need help figuring out how to do both format and input the correct text based on selection in another cell.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest - for each value in the drop down list - you define the input fields in a seperate sheet, together with field labels and formats. After selection from the drodown, you scan the parameter table and copy whatever is listed for that parameter to your input sheet.

Example (range named InputParams):

```
ParamVal    InputLabel     InputField
X           StartDate      (empty but formatted)
X           EndDate        (empty but formatted)
Y           Foo            default_Foo
Y           Bar            default_Bar
```

Upon selecting "X" from the dropdown list you walk through `InputParams` and,
`If InputParams(Idx, 1) = DropDownValue Then` copy cells `InputParams(Index,2)` and `InputParams(Index,3)` to your input range - by default formats are copied along with content.

It is desireable to define a named range also for Input, giving it a size of maximum parameters expected, so that you can clear content and formats with one single statement prior to re-populating this range when walking through the InputParams list.